# How to calculate coefficient of friction of given surface?

Tags: friction

I have a surface in real life whose coefficient of kinetic friction I need to calculate. I've seen a method where people attempt to measure the angle at which the object on top begins to slide off the bottom surface, but the upper object here is essentially a sphere, so rolling begins immediately. The method only needs to be reasonably accurate, and should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Do you want the coefficient of static friction or kinetic friction?

Comment: Kinetic, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: It should be noted that single surfaces don't have coefficients of friction. You have to specify both surfaces. And if those surfaces aren't sliding past each other (like in rolling without slipping) then you're out of luck. Why do you have to have a sphere?